# CRS of Shapely Object

Tags: python, postgis, coordinate-system, shapely

I've imported a row from a Postgres DB using sqlalchemy.

One of the column types is GEOMETRY from postgis and upon import

```
>>>> type(row[0].geom)
```

returns

```
class 'geoalchemy2.elements.WKBElement'
```

I convert to a shapely polygon (the object type I need)

```
boundary_geom = row[0].geom
shapely_geom = to_shape(boundary_geom)

>>>> type(shapely_geom)
<class 'shapely.geometry.multipolygon.MultiPolygon'>
```

I'm trying to check the crs before using the object but it does not appear to have one.

I checked in the database

```
select ST_SRID(geom) from public.inner_london_boundary;
```

returns

```
27700
```

for the row in question

27700 is British national grid which is what is expected.

The Well Know Binary data passed to the function should contain the SRID.

edit: i just checked and it does:

```
>>>> boundary_geom.srid
27700
```

Why is the shapely object missing the projection metadata?

Am I just checking for it incorrectly?

do I need to set it manually no matter what?

Comment: Try this:  `boundary_geom.crs`

Comment: `>>>>boundary_geom.crs` returns `<sqlalchemy.sql.functions._FunctionGenerator object at 0x0E25E6B0>` but I can check the crs of that `WKBElement` successfully with `boundary_geom.srid`. It's the `shapely_geom` that I'm trying to check and `>>>> shapely_geom.crs` returns `AttributeError: 'MultiPolygon' object has no attribute 'crs'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shapely is wholly unaware of the coordinate system of the geometries. You have to keep track of the CRS yourself.

> Shapely does not support coordinate system transformations. All operations on two or more features presume that the features exist in the same Cartesian plane.

https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#coordinate-systems

To do transformations, you have to use another library (such as pyproj) to create them. Shapely can execute the transformation for you, though.

https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#other-transformations